# Diffusion equation with Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider equation
$\frac{∂u}{∂t}−\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}= 0, 0 ≤ x ≤ l$,

subject to Neumann BCs

$u_x(0, t) = 0, u_x(l, t) = 0,$
and initial condition $u(x, 0) = f(x)$,
where $f(x) = sin(x(l − x))$.

Show that $u(x, t) = u(l − x, t)$ for all $x ∈ [0, l]$ and all $t ≥ 0$.

I'm unsure where to start with this proof, however I know how to show that the solution is unique and think that this would be helpful when proving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea to start. You know that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the heat equation, so perhaps see if you can differentiate $u(l-x,t)$ with respect to space and time and see if it looks like the heat equation.  Then, as you said, you know something about uniqueness.  So if you find that $u(l-x,t)$ solves the same problem as $u(x,t)$, what can you conclude?

Comment: So differentiate $u(l-x,t)$ with respect to $t$ and $x$ and plug it back into the diffusion equation?

Comment: @ross Well, does $u(l-x,t)$ satisfy the heat equation with the given boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: @ross and so you know that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the equation, and so does $u(l-x,t)$, so by uniqueness, what can we conclude?

Comment: So far I've got that; Let $w(x,t)=u(l-x,t)$, and we need to show that $w(x,t)\equiv{u(x,t)}$. Look at BC's; $w_x(x,t)=\frac{d}{dx}(u(l-x,t))=u_x(l-x,t)$. So $w_x(0,t)=u_x(l,t)=0,$ and $w_x(l,t)=u_x(0,t)=0$. So these satisfy the BC's

Comment: I'm unsure how to show that the initial condition is satisfied, as I have that $w(x,0)=u(l-x,0)=f(l-x)$ and the fact that $f(x)=sin(x(l-x))$ is throwing me off?

Comment: @ross yes, and also $w_t(x,t) - w_{xx}(x,t) = 0,$ as well as $w(x,0) = sin(x(l-x))$.  Therefore we have two solutions to the PDE.  By uniqueness, we must have that $w = u$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: @ross to show they both satisfy the initial condition, just substitute $l-x$ everywhere in the IC that there is an $x$.  So we have $u(l-x,0) = \sin((l-x)(l-(l-x)))$ which simplifies to $u(l-x,0) = \sin((l-x)x)$.